# Oбьединить две DataFrame таблицы, провести агрегацию данных с помощью pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Написал код:

```
array = pd.DataFrame(np.object, index=[], columns=[])
array = array.append({'Project': b.name, 'Summary': card.name, \
                  'Key': card.id, 'Assignee': m, 'Points': s}, \
                  ignore_index=True)
array1 = pd.read_excel('ProjectCostUCP.xlsx', 'Лист1')
result = array[['Project', 'Assignee', 'Points']].groupby(['Project', 
              'Assignee']).sum(axis=1)
print(result.columns.tolist()) 
result = result.merge(array1, on=['Project'])
result['Value'] = result.Points * result.Price
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('third.xlsx')
array.to_excel(writer, "June")
result.to_excel(writer, "June_agregation")
writer.save()
```

Нужно обьединить две таблицы - result и array1 по наименованию колонки - 'Project'. Но, как показывает строчка print(result.columns.tolist()) в таблице result только одна колонка - 'Points'. Хотя до операции groupby() была еще и колонка 'Project'. groupby() поместил 'Project' в какой-то MultiIndex, с которого я не могу вытянуть данные. 
Помогите, пожалуйста, как исправить код, чтобы он заработал ?
Конечным результатом работы кода, должна быть таблица:

```
Project    Assignee Price   Points  Value
srnd-demo   Serhii  5,5     23      126,5
```

а после выполнения строчки

```
result = array[['Project', 'Assignee','Points']].groupby(['Project', 
          'Assignee']).sum(axis=1)
```

получается таблица:

```
                     Points
Project    Assignee 
srnd-demo   Serhii   23
```

Points - оказались наименованием Columns, а Project    Assignee попали в тип MultiIndex, с которым не возможно работать (а именно вытягивать с него данные)
таблица array1 имеет вид:

```
Project    Price
srnd-demo  5.5
```

где Project    Price - это название columns. 
Нужно обьединить таблицы result и array1 по названию columns Project, после чего перемножить Price на Points и поместить значение в колонку Value.
Использование

```
result.reset_index().merge(array1)
```

привело к созданию таблицы:

```
   Project     Assignee  Price_x  Points  Price_y
0  srnd-demo   Serhii      5.5    23.0      5.5
```

Как добится, чтобы все-таки Price в таблице была одна?

Comment: Вы можете привести пример данных, которые позволят воспроизвести проблему и показать что вы хотите получить на выходе?

Comment: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL / etc.?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060)

Comment: В конечном результате должна появится таблица:

Comment: я добавил подробное описание проблемы в задачу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь методом `.reset_index()` чтобы превратить все столбцы индекса/мульти-индекса в обычные столбцы:

```
In [245]: result
Out[245]:
                    Points
Project   Assignee
srnd-demo Serhii        23

In [246]: array1
Out[246]:
     Project  Price
0  srnd-demo    5.5

In [247]: result.reset_index().merge(array1)
Out[247]:
     Project Assignee  Points  Price
0  srnd-demo   Serhii      23    5.5
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Если в DataFrame's присутствуют столбцы с одинаковыми наименованиями, которые не учавствуют в объединении (т.е. не были указаны в качестве параметра `on`, `left_on`, `right_on`), то в результате у этих столбцов появятся суффиксы (по умолчанию: `'_x'` - для левого DF и `'_y'` - для правого).

Пример:

```
In [259]: result
Out[259]:
                    Points  Price
Project   Assignee
srnd-demo Serhii        23    5.5

In [260]: array1
Out[260]:
     Project  Price
0  srnd-demo    5.5

In [257]: result.reset_index().merge(array1, on='Project')
Out[257]:
     Project Assignee  Points  Price_x  Price_y
0  srnd-demo   Serhii      23      5.5      5.5
```

избавьтесь от дублирующих столбцов в одном из DF:

```
In [258]: result.reset_index().merge(array1.drop(['Price'], axis=1), on='Project')
Out[258]:
     Project Assignee  Points  Price
0  srnd-demo   Serhii      23    5.5
```

Comment: Да, похоже это выход из ситуации, но вместо одной Price функция reset_index() сделала две:   Price_x  и Price_y -  и у той и у другой значение 5.5 - как это исправить?

Comment: @SergiyBaraban, приведите __воспроизводимый__ пример данных ;-) Я вам не просто так ссылку в комментариях оставил...

Comment: Использование

    result.reset_index().merge(array1)
привело к созданию таблицы:

          Project     Assignee  Price_x  Points  Price_y
    0  srnd-demo   Serhii      5.5         23.0      5.5
Как добится, чтобы все-таки Price в таблице была одна?

Comment: в основном тексте вопроса добавил команду и какая таблица получается в результате

Comment: Ну не может появиться столбец `Price` в `result` после `result = array[['Project', 'Assignee','Points']].groupby(['Project', 
          'Assignee']).sum(axis=1)`. Что-то вы недоговариваете...

Comment: нет, это он после обьединения получается, конечно же, но не Price а Price_x и Price_y

Comment: я не знаю как в коментарий таблицу и код вставить, чтобы нормально смотрелось...

Comment: не надо в комментарий - лучше в вопрос

Comment: чтобы получился такой результат столбец `Price` должен присутствовать в обоих объединяемых DF

Comment: Добавил в вопрос - смотрите со строчки result.reset_index().merge(array1) - под ней есть общий вид таблицы, которая получается

Comment: спасибо большое, Вы решили мою проблему!